# Possible to have ampersands ("&") in URL BEFORE the query string?

Tags: url, redirect, ampersand, windows-server

My client is determined to have a page at `/nfm&t` so I made a directory named `nfm&t` with an *index.html* (to test) and that URL is still throwing a 404. So apparently it's not that easy.

Any ideas? Or is there a way to just redirect `nfm&t` to `nfmt`, so that the URL at least resolves?

This is a Windows server, by the way, which throws a wrench into how I'm used to doing redirects.

Comment: Did you try proper encoding like `/nfm%26t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on [AllowRestrictedChars](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) and enabling [VersionCompatibility](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a Windows Server throw a wrench into how you do redirects? If you are using IIS 7, you can use [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/). It is built into IIS. If you are using IIS 6, there is [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/), which is an external module. Both use the same syntax as mod_rewrite for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a /nfm directory? If you don't, try making one. Either way, put in a Default.aspx file and have it spit back at you the exact path it's trying to access. Chances are, when you have this here, it will go to `example.com/nfm/Default.aspx` and let you run something from there.

If you do get to that directory, then try redirection to `example.com/nfm%26t` and see if it works. If this still doesn't help it, then you're SOL

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my Snow Leopard ( OSX 10.6.2 ) workstation with Apache and it works. That is from Firefox 3.6. Looks like a Windows thing you are struggling with. Honestly I didn't think that would work without encoding but you never know until you try.

[alt text http://www.vertigrated.com/images/so_screenshot.png](http://www.vertigrated.com/images/so_screenshot.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a way to just redirect
>   nfm&t to nfmt, so that the URL at
>   least resolves?

Sure.  Make a general url handler and/or an error handler.  When it encounters a url, if that url is equal to `/nfm&t`, then under the hood rewrite the context to whatever page you actually really want to return.  Is this a good idea? Probably not.  But it will work.  Keith's answer suggests two ways to grab the url and do stuff, though you could also do this via a global asax file (being careful to execute an aspx page when you hit an error so it actually gets hit) if you're using .Net.